# vertical align forms, text etc

Tags: html, css

Good day everyone, i have the following example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FU5rY/1/) and my problem is that i don't understand how to align the text and the form vertical as you can see i used half  of the height of search-bar as line-height but i'm not sure it's right and for the form i used margin-top 18px. Can someone please correct the code and explain to me how do it the right way ?

HTML:

```
<div class="search-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form class="horizontal-form" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="sitesearch" class="site-search" value="Enter a word...">
            <input type="button" name="start_search" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
}
.search-bar {
    background-color: #e56038;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 70px;
    height: auto;

}
.search-bar p {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
}
.search-bar .form-group {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.search-bar form input {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 7px;
    outline: 0;
    border:0;
    background: #EBE8DE;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.search-bar form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.search-bar form input[type=button] {
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    text-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #333333;
    color: #fff;
}
.search-bar form input[type=button]:hover {
    background: #EBE8DE;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question? Are you asking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What is the best way to align vertical a single line of text, a paragraph and a form, i provided a sample code where i'm doing the testing with a horizontal form and a single line of text including what i've used to align it.

Comment: What is your expected result? Any screenshot?

Comment: i do not have a screenshot of the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using margin-top to adjust your elements manually is fine. I wouldn't use the line height to center the text on the left.
If you really want to center something vertically you need table behaviour. You can realize this with display:table and display:table-cell while still using div tags.

Comment: i know about the ideea of two containers one with table display and the other as a cell but i was hoping for something more elegant :-) :D and how about the part with margin-top what can i use there ? :D

Comment: There is no vertical align except in table cells. If you don't really need it just center visual with margin, position: relative, position: absolute or padding.

Comment: yes i knew that vertical belongs to tables and everything else.. is only a hack and things like that :D :-) but thanks to everyone who took time and read my posts :-)

Answer (score 1):

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TK6rF/)

You can use the code shown below, but I tried this in your JSFiddle and it didn't work.  Now, this is probably because you need to do a bit more reassessment for your styles to make this fit in.

But what you're trying to do is not bad either. It works and make sure to test it across browsers, responsiveness, etc.

```
display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
```